# clarification on F# match syntax

Tags: f#

I am trying to clarify something that's a bit fuzzy for me:

```
let a, b = true, 3
match a, b with
| true, x -> sprintf "true %i" x
| false, _ -> "false"
```

in the first match case, true is matched and the value of b is assigned to x.
the first part I have trouble 'accepting' is that 'true' is read for the comparison, but x is assigned

but then does that mean:

```
match a, b with
| c, x -> sprintf "true %b %i" c x
| false, _ -> "false"
```

will always match the first statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Match expressions always try to match values against a pattern. There are many [different types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) of patterns that can be matched. What you have here are constant patterns (in the case of matching against `true` or `false`) and variable patterns (in the case of matching against `c, x`). A constant pattern will match if the value being compared equals that constant - a variable pattern will match any input and assign the value of the input to the variable.

Matching `a, b` against the pattern `c, x` is basically matching it against any unconstrained tuple of size 2 and simultaneously assigning the values of `a` and `b` to new names `c` and `x`. In effect, what you have is the same as:

```
match a, b with
| _, _ -> sprintf "true %b %i" a b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. Using variables in the match expression is similar to using the underscore (in the latter case you just don't intend to use it). A variable is always a 100% match, as it just catches whatever is in that position of the match.

Your second example will raise a warning that the last line never matches.

Your first example can also be written like this:

```
let a, b = true, 3
match a with
| true -> sprintf "true %i" b
| false -> "false"
```